# Можно ли создать класс и объект в java из XML-файла "на лету"?

Tags: java, xml, рефлексия

Есть XML с такой структурой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object type="People">
    <field id="name" type="class java.lang.String" value="Ivan"/>
    <field id="age" type="class java.lang.Integer" value="23"/>
    <field id="salary" type="double" value="50.0"/>
</object>
```

Но тип объекта и поля могут отличаться.
Например, файл может быть таким:

```
<object type="Worker">
    <field id="lastName" type="class java.lang.String" value="Ivan"/>
    <field id="height" type="double" value="170.00"/>
    <field id="salary" type="double" value="50.0"/>
</object>
```

Можно ли создать из подобного документа объект?

Comment: XML -> Json -> Gson (та-даам)

Comment: Интересная задача, плюсую. Давайте поразмышляем. Как я понял, у вас файл должен превратиться в класс с какими-то переменными. Использовать рефлексию, если честно, вариант не очень. Можно создать **один** класс и составлять коллекцию. Насчёт названия класса - можно сохранять значение `<object type="тут"`как обычную строку. Теперь сами переменные с данными. Можно выдирать строку типа `java.lang.String` и создавать из него класс через `Class.forName()`

Comment: Но! Вы не можете предусмотреть какой тип будет использован. Сколько максимум можео быть переменных? Окей, 5. А, допустим типов 3 - `int`, `double`, `String`. Берём каждый тип в виде строки и проверяем "руками". Если `java.lang.String`, то берём значение и пихаем в переменную заранее обзывая её как в файле

Comment: Тьфу ты, это же невозможно. Автор, вам точно надо назвать класс и переменные  как в файле. Кто плюсунал мой первый коммент? Я это не в серьёзно написал.))

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, можно. Смотрите в сторону генерации байт-кода. Например:
   [cglib](https://github.com/cglib)
2. Оно вам не нужно. Воспользуйтесь сериализацией.

   1. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
   2. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: `Jackson` для парсинга `xml` в `json`, а `gson` для парсинга `json` в `pojo`? Я прав?

Comment: @Flippy, Jackson умеет xml <-> pojo и json <-> pojo. А gson для работы с json в качестве альтернативного варианта.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать :)